# WordPress site without db table prefix. Best way to add a prefix?

Tags: database, wordpress

I'm trying to migrate a WordPress site to some new hosting. The site is an older site, created probably 7+ years ago. I'm getting an error from wordpress upon bringing it to the new server that gave me a heads-up that the WP tables have no prefix. Sure enough, I login to Phpmyadmin, and there are no prefixes on the tables. I have since tried several methods to add prefixes and get the site migrated, but all are coming up short:

1. Direct DB dump from phpmyadmin on old server, import into new server. Triggers "tables have no prefix" error
2. Use updraft plus to get the backup from old server, restore to new server (triggers "tables have no prefix" fatal error)
3. Revised #1(above) approach - db dump/import/restore, manually add (via operations tab in each table) wp_ prefix to all tables. Site loads, but logging in as admin then yields no access to wp-admin dashboard (black bar at top after login, but no options for doing anything on the dashboard). I have tried the various tricks suggested, like adding a new temp admin user or trying to make necessary changes in usermeta table to my admin user, but that doesn't resolve it.
4. Tried using the All In One WP Security plugin to add new prefix. It recognizes the current no prefix, but won't successfully complete adding the prefixes to the DB. Tried another plugin and didn't even get that far.
5. Using Phpmyadmin, I've tried to use the built-in add prefix, and that seems to not work either.

I just looked at phpmyadmin again after trying unsuccessfully to use the built-in add prefix function, and am noticing that while all tables are InnoDB, the collation is a mix of utf8_general_ci and utf8mb4_unicode_ci  . I understand that the second option is probably what I want all of them to be. I was able to add prefixes to the tables that are utf8mb4_unicode_ci, but the rest of them simply do not respond to that function in phpmyadmin.

The next thing I tried was to change all the collation to utf8mb4_unicode_ci using phpmyadmin. I used the "change all tables collations" and "change all tables columns collations". That seemed to work and then allowed me to add a prefix. However, after that, while the site was still working, I could again no longer get into the wp-admin dashboard. If I were to try the same conversion but only doing the "change all tables collations" and skipping the second option, I wonder if that might work. Just tried converting the tables without converting all the columns. The site seems to still work ok after doing that. But trying again to add prefix using the AIO WP security plugin still doesn't complete.

It would seem that adding the prefix is causing the issue. Is this something that a theme could be interfering with for some reason? What am I missing here?

Any tips for moving forward with this site? Thanks so much.

Comment: I should also note - the site is running on an NGINX server. I've restarted the MariaDB service several times after some of these changes to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply dump the database, open it with a text editor, replace all occurrences of "CREATE TABLE " with "CREATE TABLE yourprefix_" and restore the database.
It should be easy, depending on the size of the dump.

Comment: thanks, maybe I'll give that a try. I had also started down that path, but hadn't followed through. Based on the dump, it looks like I'll need to change:
CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO and ALTER TABLE

Comment: tried that. The site works but I don't have full access to wp-admin dashboard after logging in. Do I need to do a search/replace of something in the database that might be referencing a non-prefixed table name? Something in usermeta that might hold the key to the permissions? At the moment, I'm doing this work on the old server, so domain/URL isn't changing in any fashion.

Comment: What kind of error do you get?